# Got the error when use LUA script to query a list

Tags: lua, redis

when I use Lua script to query a list, I got the correctly result if the list is not empty. But got error if the list is empty.

Blow is my script:

```
const char * sLuaQueryServers = "local key_list = redis.call('KEYS',
KEYS[1]); return(redis.call('MGET', unpack(key_list)))";
```

I passed the "serverlist:*" as the key, it's successfully returned the server in list.

But if there no server in redis, I got below error:

```
ERR Error running script (call to 
f_88620231033e13635dc3181f2947a740f91012dc): @user_script:1: @user_script: 
1: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question, add a check that the list isn't empty before calling `MGET`, e.g.:

```
local key_list = redis.call('KEYS', KEYS[1])
if #key_list > 0 then
  return(redis.call('MGET', unpack(key_list)))
else
  return nil
end
```

Note #1: no need for semicolons in Lua

Note #2: Using `KEYS` isn't recommended for anything, except debugging

Note #3: You're using the `KEYS` table to pass an argument, but since your script is running `KEYS` (the command) that's really a moot point

Comment: Thank you Itamar, so for your Note #2, how can I rewrite the script to instead of the KEYS ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do - scanning the keyspace in runtime is both blocking and slow and should be avoided